# Правильно ли поставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Зимняя верхняя одежда, которая по своим свойствам намного превосходит изделия, в которых утеплителем является пух, – пуховики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно поставлены. А два "которых" не смущают?

З.Ы. Слишком короткие ответы очень не нравятся этому сайту, поэтому приходится лить вот эту воду, за что и прошу извинить. )